How to tell my boss that he's a moron and in office work won't fix anything
So I work for a small tech company (under 10 of us) where we do a bit of R&D and tech support with some test benches and some hardware.
My boss is in his 40s so not quite a boomer but does seem to have this disillusion view of in person office work as if that's the only way that any work gets done. I've been able to demand WFH for 2 days a week but realistically the commute is still a killer and 95% of my work can be done remotely. The only reason I have this current WFH is I threw the book at them (we're in the UK so our laws about flexible working just changed).
He maintains that remote work doesn't work for him because he prefers everyone in the office as that's how HE best communicates and wants people there 'just in case'. He also insists on using what's app group for our instant messages and is a bit slow on following threads and replies so when there is the slightest bit of inconvenience for him he will just get frustrated and say 'Aghh this is why we need everyone in the office'.
Furthermore, he refuses to use any management tools and barely uses the ticket desk, has no interest in any solutions we have suggested to him because he's embarrassed that we know more than him in some capacity.
It's getting to the point where he is insisting on using spreadsheets to track everything and whiteboards, and if i can prove it he's keeping customer encryption keys in random notes in plain text.
It's chaos, and if you go against it you're an 'idiot'.
Has anyone had a similar situation to this before? If he took a step back we could manage stuff without him fine, but he insists on micromanaging and trying to be involved in EVERY customer issue. Which as you can guess slows things down exponentially.

Obligatory: why do you want to keep working there?

As a corollary, what do your coworkers think about this? Do they want to keep working there?

Remember that this may be a decision your boss's boss made, and he may be stuck with implementing it whether he agrees or not. Calling him a moron is not going to help you solve this. Trying to work with him to find compromises, and gradually change the culture over an extended period of time, my. If you need things to change now rather than in a few years, the way to do that is to find employment with a company which is more friendly to remote work. And not everyone is suited to remote work; it requires additional skills both in time management and in communication. See related questions.

Well, he is the boss. That means that your job is to make him more successful, not necessarily make the customer happy.

You can tell your supervisor they are a moron but that’s a guarantee way of finding yourself in a situation where you’ll need a new supervisor.

If he's in his 40's, he's not even close to being a Boomer.  The very youngest of GenX is in their late 40s.  He's probably a Millennial.  That being said, he sounds as though he's not had any management or leadership training. He also seems resistant to getting any. This is his world. You need to decide if you want to live in it or not. I will say YOUR attitude seems to need some serious improvement, though.

what was the arrangement w.r.t. remote work when you discussed the offer to join?

My last business partner was like that.  Some staff  kept leaving and some remained for over a decade.  The ones that remained had a saying "Treat him like a mushroom" (meaning keep him in the dark and feed him BS).
Basically, you either live with it or leave.  If he regards you as valuable he will give in more.  But it is unlikely that he is going to have a sudden change of heart.  It is your decision.

What are you hoping for from us random internet people? For the most part we try to be pragmatic and find solutions to problems. Your solution is very clear from your OP.
The bottom line is ----> Quit.
You don't like the critera for working there. Quit.
You don't like the location of the work. Quit.
You don't respect the boss. Quit.
You don't like the tools the boss will/won't use. Quit.
You are smarter that the boss. Quit and start your own business. That is what I did 40 years ago so I can speak with a bit a knowledge on the subject.
It comes down to this:

Do it
Ask for clarification
Explain why they are wrong
Quit

The first three haven't worked. That leaves the fourth.
The world is full of "Monday morning quarterbacks". FYI for the folks not in the US, this is an American colloquialism. It means experts after-the-fact or people who think they know better but don't actually risk anything. I find that the OP reeks of it.

The last paragraph seems entirely unnecessary, it's just being rude to the OP.

@Erik - The OP is calling their boss a "Moron". Their words, not mine. The OP could use a reality check on the employer / employee relationship and the concept of respect. If you consider that rude, then we'll agree to disagree on this subject. Consider your position when you DV my answer.

I agree with your sentiment, but you can share it in a respectable way, or you do it in a rude way. You chose the latter.

@Erik - Somebody needs to say the truth. I have said the same thing to my own employees over the years and as recently as this week. The OP seems to want to do a good job, but thinks they are more important to the business than the boss. They are wrong. The sooner that the OP becomes a team player, the sooner the OP will be promoted to be the boss. What you consider rude, I consider direct.

Unfortunately the administrative competence of management has been falling for years, as has the quality and homeliness of office space and its distance from workers' homes, and both matters have really come to a head where workers are resistant to even being in the office anymore, and yet it is apparent that most work is still getting done.
In the end, it comes down to whether you will walk out the door or not. That's the real bottom line of the negotiation. Your manager by the sounds of it is either unsuited to managing a remote workforce (in the sense that his skills or preferences are irreconcilable to it), or is being shown to be redundant to a displeasing extent, and therefore it is unlikely that any argument you can ply will prove decisive.
The tension for all businesses from now on, is that not only does office space and parking space cost money (especially quality space where workers actually enjoy being), but so does commuting time and costs which have to be covered via wages, and so does childcare particularly for women.
Most will simply find over time that they cannot afford not to leverage remote workers, because otherwise their wage bill will be tens of thousands higher per person, and their overall facilities bill probably thousands higher per person, and as office leases expire or smaller companies outgrow what they already have, that is when there will be real questions about whether they want to pay the additional costs.
